# Generify method returning children of the same interface

Tags: typescript

I can't find a way to create a single generic function that returns child interfaces inheriting the same parent interface.

Basically, I would like to implement the `getById` method:

```js
interface Car { brand: string }
interface Ford extends Car { someUniqueAttribe: string }
interface Ferrari extends Car { someOtherUniqueAttribute: string }

const aFord: Ford = getById<Ford>('1')
const aFerrari: Ferrari = getById<Ferrari>('2')
```

I tried two ways:

## With `generic`:

```js
interface CarRepository {
  getById<C extends Car>(id : string): C
}

class CarRepositoryImpl implements CarRepository {
 public getById<C extends Car> (id: string): C {
   return id === '1'
     ? { brand: 'Ford', someUniqueAttribe: 'foo' }
     : { brand: 'Ferrari', someOtherUniqueAttribute: 'bar' }
  }
}
```

But it yields the error:

```
TS2322: Type '{ brand: string; }' is not assignable to type 'C'.   
    '{ brand: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'C', but 'C' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Car'
```

## With `method overloads`:

```js
interface CarRepository {
  getById(id : string): Ford
  getById(id : string): Ferrari
}

class CarRepositoryImpl implements CarRepository {
 public getById (id: string): Ford | Ferrari {
   return id === '1'
     ? { brand: 'Ford', someUniqueAttribe: 'foo' }
     : { brand: 'Ferrari', someOtherUniqueAttribute: 'bar' }
  }
}
```

But it yields the error:

```
Property 'getById' in type 'CarRepositoryImpl' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'CarRepository'.
  Type '(id: string) => Ford | Ferrari' is not assignable to type '{ (id: string): Ford; (id: string): Ferrari; }'.
    Type 'Ford | Ferrari' is not assignable to type 'Ford'.
      Property 'someUniqueAttribe' is missing in type 'Ferrari' but required in type 'Ford'.(2416)
```

Once again, I understand what's wrong for TypeScript but I can't the appropriate implementation. Is there a way to achieve this in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getById` should return a Car object, which could be either a `Ford` or `Ferrari` and then implement a function `static isFord(potentialFord: any) { /* check for someUniqueAttribute */ }` and the same on `Ferrari` and then after calling `getById` check whether you got a `Ford` or `Ferrari`.

> This also gives you the ability to query a database before knowing what car you will get